# Javascript: Get radio-button value from another html page

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

**Hi everybody!**

**Background:**
I currently build an online unit-converter which be can be seen under 
http://okconvert.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=126&Itemid=1262 .
In the bottom left corner you find an orange button named "Conversion Settings". After a click on this button, the user shall be able to select how exact his unit conversions shall be. He/She chooses an accuracy (for example 3 or 4 digits), then clicks "Apply settings".

When the user actually does a conversion afterwards, he clicks on the button "Ok, convert!" and a javascript is called which calculates results.

**Question**
Which would be the smartest way to access the value of the selected radio button from the pop-up in the javascript?
I googled a lot and found some answers but none of them really seems to suite my needs. Here are two possibilities I'm considering:

- Using HTML5 local storage (I need to have a default conversion-accuracy, so this might not be useful because applying conversion settings shall only be optional)
- Using jQuery/Ajax to load the custom html and use some kind of GetElementbyID for the loaded page

**Additional information**
After clicking on the orange button, a "JCE Mediabox" is opened which is filled with some custom html. The pop-up actually links to the custom html page, so I could access that url if needed.
I have some basic knowledge about javascript, html and css but have never used jqueries/ajax before.

Any help or hints would be highly appreciated!

With best regards,
Felix
http://www.okconvert.com

Comment: Is the dialog not part of the parent html . Global javascript values wont serve your purpose ?

Answer (score 1):

How about dropping the value in a cookie. It's simple enough, keeps the state on the client and works over all windows and popups you care to open.

Comment: Yeah, that's along the lines that I was thinking, though it's a lot easier with stuff like C# session state. If it /had/ to be done in JavaScript, though, I think I'd much prefer jQuery or writing a variable to the URL.

Comment: Agreed, if you have a state-full system a quick ajax-call home would be a good solution. If not, I'd still prefer the cookie over the URL as it stays up-to-date even when you change the radio after the popup has already been opened.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point. As far as ease of use is concerned, the URL would probably be easier, but a lot less secure than a cookie.

Comment: Hi Guys,

thanks for the response! As far I understand it, the cookie-solution should be simpler than the solution with ajax?

For the cookie-solution: How would you realize a default value?
Maybe something like:

[pseudocode of the .js-file]
Before calculation, check for the value in the cookie and take it as precision. If cookie is not available (is this possible?), take default value 

On the other hand, for the Ajax-solution: I would have to use the jquery.js file and use the .load or .get-operation..?

Thanks! :)

Comment: I think the "sessionStorage" option of html5 sounds most promising for my problem, I'll give it a try and let you know if it worked.

http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/07/21/introduction-to-sessionstorage/